# In JaCaMo JCM file, how to deal with multiple instances in organisation configurations?

Tags: agent, multi-agent

I am trying to create multiple agents using "instances" which makes easier when we need to increment the number of instances many times. It is clear how to do it in "agent level" by jcm file. But the point is how to do it in "organisation level" since I may have many names.

My jcm file is like this, note that "p*" is my question.

```
mas auctionAEO {

    agent a : auctioneerA.asl {
        beliefs:    total(10)
    } 
    agent p : participantA.asl {
        instances:  10
    }

    organisation aorg : auction-os.xml {
        group agrp : auctionGroup {
            players: a  auctioneer
                     p* participant
            debug
        }
    }

    asl-path: src/agt
              src/agt/inc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the roles of the agents in the "agent" declaration. 
For instance:

```
agent p : participantA.asl {
    instances:  10
    roles:      participant in agrp
}
```

In JaCaMo distribution, the doc folder contains the jcm.html file that lists all options for JCM files.